# How to get the bluetooth name/id of Samsung Gear S3 smartwatch web application

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am trying to get the bluetooth name/id in a tizen web-application running on Gear S3. 
On the watch, this information can be found -
Settings -> Connections -> Bluetooth -> Bluetooth Gear S3(**AAA1**).

I want the **AAA1** value programmatically. Is there any method or API to get the value in a tizen web-application ?

Comment: please check the answer and response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the **discoverDevices** function, You will find the BluetoothDevice interface on the **succesCallback** parameter.

BluetoothDevice interface represents a remote Bluetooth device having the propertoes:

DOMString **name**;

BluetoothAddress **address**;

BluetoothClass **deviceClass**;

boolean **isBonded**;

boolean **isTrusted**;

boolean **isConnected**;

BluetoothUUID[] **uuids**;

**name** is the property you are looking for. 
In your case the name is: 'Gear S3(AAA1)'

```
var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();

var discoverDevicesSuccessCallback = {
        ondevicefound: function(device) {
            alert('Found device - name: ' + device.name);
        }
    };

adapter.discoverDevices(discoverDevicesSuccessCallback, null);
```

Add 'bluetooth.gap' privilege (for Tizen 2.3.2 and below) or 'bluetooth' privilege (for Tizen 3.0 and above) in your config.xml:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth.gap"/>  // <=2.3.2
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth"/>     // >=3.0
```

Additionally, If you need only 'AAA1' instead of 'Gear S3 (AAA1)', May try a little Regular Expression and split.

```
var deviceName = "Gear S3 (AAA1)";                  // Gear S3 (AAA1)
var removePrts = deviceName.replace(/[()]/g,'');    // Gear S3 AAA1
var shortName = removePrts.split(' ');              // Gear,S3,AAA1
alert(shortName[2]);                                // AAA1
```